# Powershell Import-Clixml from a shared network folder using full UNC - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to run a powershell script inside a SQL Agent job.  I keep getting the error:  Import-Clixml : The system cannot find the file specified.  At \Data\Powershell\Collibra\Dev\test.ps1:95   char:21  + ... redential = Import-Clixml -Path Filesystem::\Data\Powershell...  +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Clixml], Cryptographic      Exception      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicExcept      ion,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportClixmlCommand

```
      $Credential = Import-Clixml -Path 
      Filesystem::\\energy\data\apps\BISharedServices\Powershell\Collibra\Dev\credentials.xml
      $username = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
      $password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
      $credPair = "$($username):$($password)"
      $encodedCredentials =       [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))
      $H = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }
```

I have tried mapping a new drive and doing a set-location.  Same results.  This is driving me nuts!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic Powershell without SSIS at least, it's only one slash at the beginning:

```
Import-Clixml -Path FileSystem::\path\to\file.txt
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help.